# Android: host is not reachable

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just run the below code as a normal java class file and status.isReachable(3000) returns true.

```
InetAddress status = InetAddress.getByName("android.com");

status.isReachable(3000);
```

If i run the same code from the Android Project, `status.isReachable(3000)` always return false. Why is it returning false? Will it always returns false in the Emulator. I had also read this post
[why-inetaddress-getbyname-isreachable-works-on-device-but-not-on-the-eclipse][1]

What I have done so far:

-kept the permission on the mainfest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

-disable my firewall.

-ping the android.com from my PC, the host is reachable

I was doing this to check whether the address in the preference is dead or alive

Comment: Did you get it working? please answer your question if you have found an answer..

Comment: No, i haven't found the solution for it. Instead I removed that portion of code from my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar kind of problem where my map app background was grey (no tiles) and the browser was unable to connect to the internet.

Within Eclipse I went to Run Configurations -> Target and added "-dns-server X.X.X.X" and everything worked fine afterwards. (obviously X.X.X.X was the IP address for my DNS server).